# Generic term for certificates and keys

Tags: public-key-infrastructure

Is there a generic term to designate both public and private keys, certificates and maybe even passwords?

Comment: by adding "passwords" to your list, I'm not sure what you are asking for

Comment: @schroeder forget about the passwords then

Comment: Yes - "stuff" covers it.

Comment: If you include the need for CAs to ensure a cert is trusted & valid, then `PKI` might fit the bill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Credentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Credential#Cryptography) seems appropriate.

Comment: Would credentials not also encompass user / name / email / Telephone# / Location ?

Comment: I'm not sure that a private key should be used as a credential

Comment: @LawrivanBuël other things such as biometrics would also be credentials.

Comment: According to the link "Usually they take the form of machine-readable cryptographic keys and/or passwords". That's about as close a match as you're gonna get.

Comment: My remark is meant to question scope (is Credentials not to big in scope for this use?), not that it does not qualify. it does. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Possible `Authentication mechanism`.
Sources :

- [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/auth.html)
- [Dovecot (An email server)](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/Mechanisms)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication)
- [techrepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-and-selecting-authentication-methods/)

Although the other suggestion of `Credentials` by @neil-smithline could also be true.

Comment: you are assuming that certs and keys are for authentication

Comment: When are they not? They always Identify something.
(A server, A client, A secret, etc.)

Comment: identity != authentication

Comment: My question was about the name of the data, or objects, not the way in which they are used

Comment: From wikipedia:  authentication is the process of actually confirming that identity [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication)

Comment: I hear you, but I think you made an error in logic. An authentication mechanism might use those things, but those things are not an authentication mechanism. Your own wiki link uses the term: authentication factor.

Comment: I am starting to suspect so as well. anyway both options are now there and the final selection should be done by OP for his use case.